# ansible lineinfile module to replace a single line with multiple lines

Tags: regex, linux, ansible, ntp

I have a ansible play which works correctly as follows, here i have two `From` entries which are being changed with `TO` entries.

But i'm just wondering if there is way where i can replace one line with two lines in a file called `ntp.conf` in my case.

```
---
- name: Play to correct the config for NTP clients
  hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
  - name: Changing the ntp server configuration on the client
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/ntp.conf
      ### line to be searched & matched
      regexp: '{{ item.From }}'
      ### line to be in placed
      line: '{{ item.To }}'
      state: present
      backup: yes
      backrefs: yes

    with_items:
    - { From: 'server ros-ntp minpoll 4 maxpoll 10', To: 'server ros-gw.fuzzy.com minpoll 4 maxpoll 10'}
    - { From: 'server ros-ntp-b minpoll 4 maxpoll 10', To: 'server ros-b-gw.fuzzy.com minpoll 4 maxpoll 10'}

    notify: restart_ntp_service

  handlers:
  - name: restart_ntp_service
    service:
      name: ntpd
      state: restarted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the work around as follows with using `lineinfile` module, still looking for the other way around if someone comes across. Just placing the working answer below for posterity ...

```
---
- name: Play to correct the config for NTP clients
  hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
  - name: Changing the ntp server configuration on the client
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/ntp.conf
      ### line to be searched & matched
      regexp: 'server ros-ntp minpoll 4 maxpoll 10'
      ### line to be in placed
      line: "server ros-ntp-b minpoll 4 maxpoll 10\nserver ros-ntp-gw minpoll 4 maxpoll 10"
      state: present
      backup: yes
      backrefs: yes
    notify: restart_ntp_service

  handlers:
  - name: restart_ntp_service
    service:
      name: ntpd
      state: restarted
```

The newline `\n` works well with version 2.3 and 2.4 qs well, just to be sure not to use `\\n` <- thi sis from the actual git commit.

> ```
>     # Replace the newline character with an actual newline. Don't replace
>     # escaped \\n, hence sub and not str.replace.
>     line = re.sub(r'\n', os.linesep, params['line'])
>     # Replace the newline character with an actual newline, but be careful
>     # not to trigger other escape sequences (specifically octal \ooo)
>     line = re.sub(r'((?<!(?:[^\\]\\))\\n)', os.linesep, params['line'])
> ```

Comment: I don't think this is going to give you the results you're after. Since the first line is your match, if you ever change it, the second line is going to be duplicated because the `lineinfile` module isn't aware of it and thus won't replace it. I'd still recommend using `blockinfile`. Alternatively you could use two `lineinfile` tasks, I added that solution to my answer as well.

Comment: @RyanFisher,  this solution works perfectly and i have posted this after using this solution.

Comment: I understand it will work the first time. The problem is when you want to make a change to either line. You can't change the second line, because it's not in the `regex:` match. You can change the first line, but it will create a duplicate second ine. See this [example](https://pastebin.com/DDPBaqq5).

Comment: @RyanFisher, Thanks for the constant inputs, However it will not duplicate anything,   here in my case i'm changing an entry in "/etc/ntp.conf" if  `server ros-ntp minpoll 4 maxpoll 10`  line looked into the file then its been replaced with two new lines as `server ros-ntp-b minpoll 4 maxpoll 10\nserver ros-ntp-gw minpoll 4 maxpoll 10` and `\n` is doing the line separation to make it literal second line.  I have used this playbook to change the setting across across 400 systems and all looks good no duplicate at all.

Comment: it won't duplicate until someone comes along and tries to change `server ros-ntp-b minpoll 4 maxpoll 10` to something different. I'd at least comment it as such, you're planting a landmine for the next person.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use `blockinfile` to add multiple lines to `ntp.conf`. You can use `lineinfile` to replace the line you're targeting with a comment, then use the `insertafter` parameter of `blockinfile` to add your lines after it.

Here is the `blockinfile` [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/blockinfile_module.html).

Alternatively you could use two `lineinfile` tasks and leverage the `insertafter` property. Something like this:

```
- name: Set NTP server to use ros-ntp-b
  lineinfile:
      path: /etc/ntp.conf
      regexp: 'server ros-ntp-?b? minpoll 4 maxpoll 10'
      line: 'server ros-ntp-b minpoll 4 maxpoll 10'
      state: present
      backup: no

- name: Add NTP server config for ros-ntp-gw
  lineinfile:
      path: /etc/ntp.conf
      regexp: 'server ros-ntp-rw minpoll 4 maxpoll 10'
      line: 'server ros-ntp-gw minpoll 4 maxpoll 10'
      insertafter: 'server ros-ntp-b minpoll 4 maxpoll 10'
      state: present
      backup: yes
```

Comment: @ Ryan, that's the way around but there might be and elegant way of doing in using something like vars, i just saw there is way of doing it [example](https://serverfault.com/questions/866921/replace-two-line-with-three-lines-using-ansible) by Konstantin Suvorov but i'm not getting it how to fit that into my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a "|-" to lineinfile works aswell, an example below.

```
---
- name: Play to correct the config for NTP clients
  hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
  - name: Changing the ntp server configuration on the client
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/ntp.conf
      ### line to be searched & matched
      regexp: 'server ros-ntp minpoll 4 maxpoll 10'
      ### line to be in placed
      line: |- 
        server ros-ntp-b minpoll 4 maxpoll 10
        server ros-ntp-gw minpoll 4 maxpoll 10
      state: present
      backup: yes
      backrefs: yes
    notify: restart_ntp_service

  handlers:
  - name: restart_ntp_service
    service:
      name: ntpd
      state: restarted
```